# How to execute git commands from bash script?

Tags: git, bash, shell

I have the following bash script to start the ssh-agent, add my keys and do a git pull on a repo. The agent is started, the key is added but the git pull doesn't execute...at least nothing is echo'd to the terminal. The git command works if I type it into the terminal...is there something I need to do within my bash script to make it work?

```
#!/bin/bash

# if we can't find an agent, start one, and restart the script.
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] ; then
  exec ssh-agent bash -c "ssh-add ; $0"
  exit
fi

exec ssh-add ~/.ssh/mykey
git --git-dir=/var/www/node/myapp/.git pull origin master
```

---

When I add -x to #!/bin/bash this is the terminal output

```
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ exec ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add ; ./startgit.sh'
+ '[' -z /tmp/ssh-<redacted>/agent.1733 ']'
+ exec ssh-add /home/ec2-user/.ssh/mykey
Identity added: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/mykey (/home/ec2-user/.ssh/mykey)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're restarting the script after the exit if `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is empty? Did you try "debugging" it (`#!/bin/bash -x` to echo the commands being run)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `exec` command replaces the current shell with the process that is executed. Therefore, the lines that follow it in your script are not executed.

From the manpage:

> **exec**: exec [-cl] [-a name] file [redirection ...]
>
> Exec FILE, replacing this shell with the specified program.
>   You should remove it from the line

```
exec ssh-add ~/.ssh/mykey
```

and simply have

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/mykey
```